# Hotel Reservation System Sql Query?

Tags: sql

I want to build a Hotel Reservation System. For this system; database is also used fro an other program... But i have problem: before the reservation i want to see which number of rooms type are available for my for my reservation..

My table create sql querys

```
CREATE TABLE oteldb.oda (
oda_id INT (11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
oda_tip_id INT (11) DEFAULT NULL,
oda_adi VARCHAR (20) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (oda_id)
)
ENGINE = MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE oteldb.tip (
tip_id INT (11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
tip_adi VARCHAR (20) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (tip_id)
)
ENGINE = MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci
ROW_FORMAT = FIXED;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE oteldb.rezervasyon (
rezervasyon_id INT (11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
rezervasyon_gt DATE DEFAULT NULL,
rezervasyon_ct DATE DEFAULT NULL,
rezervasyon_oda_id INT (11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (rezervasyon_id)
)
ENGINE = MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

---

i try this but not work

```
SELECT
*
FROM
oteldb.tip
WHERE
IN tip.tip_id
(SELECT
oteldb.oda.oda_tip_id
FROM
oteldb.oda
WHERE
IN oda.oda_id note

(SELECT
oteldb.rezervasyon.rezervasyon_oda_id
FROM
oteldb.rezervasyon
WHERE
"2012-01-03" BETWEEN AND rezervasyon_ct rezervasyon_gt
AND "2012-01-22" AND BETWEEN rezervasyon_gt rezervasyon_ct))
```

---

thanks now...

Comment: `WHERE IN tip.tip_id` should be `WHERE tip.tip_id IN `

Comment: thanx Florin Ghita & Mark Bannister, I tried but the result is not true, also can not display the number of rooms. i tihnk my query is wrong...

Comment: @Mehmet: Can you include some sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that available rooms are those that are not already reserved at any time during the query period, and that rezervasyon_gt and rezervasyon_ct are the reservation start and end dates respectively, try:

```
select t.tip_adi, count(oda.oda_tip_id)
from oteldb.tip t
left join (select oda_tip_id
           from oteldb.oda o
           where not exists
                (select null
                 from oteldb.rezervasyon r
                 where r.rezervasyon_oda_id = o.oda_id and
                       r.rezervasyon_gt <= '2012-01-22' and
                       '2012-01-03' <= r.rezervasyon_ct)
           ) oda on oda.oda_tip_id = t.tip_id
group by t.tip_adi
```

Comment: Thanks Mark the query is malfunctioning.

My database structure and data sql query follows. Thank you in advance..

[Sql Create Query](http://verigrup.net/oteldb.txt)

I converted English

Comment: @Mehmet: Using your test data, I tried running my query locally and realised that I should have been selecting `count(oda.oda_tip_id)`, not `count(*)`. I have amended my query accordingly - the amended query seems to work correctly with the test data.

Comment: Thanks Mark , i tried query again  but it also showed the reserved rooms in the date of the reservation time that has been asked.

I am sending you the link of sql chart in English  [sql table](http://verigrup.net/hotel.txt). 

for example there are 5occupied room between 2012,01,03 and 2012.01.22. it should not show the occupied room in that "type" in the "type" list. that is,if the 5 of the 8 rooms are occupied in the "type_id"=1, it should account  3 rooms that have "type_id"=1.

Comment: @Mehmet: In your amended data, only 4 rooms are type 1 (Lux) and only one of these (id 2, name "100") is booked. Another 3 rooms are type 2 (Normal) and only one of these is booked (id 3, name "200", booked twice during the relevant period). Another 2 rooms are type 3 (Eco) and only one of these is booked (id 1, name "300", booked three times during the relevant period). So, during the booking period, type 1 (Lux) has 3 rooms available, type 2 (Normal) has 2 rooms available and type 3 (Eco) has 1 room available - this is what the query returns.

Comment: @Mehmet: That's **exactly** how the query works, and **exactly** the same results that I get from running the query (see previous comment). If you get different results from running the query, please can you include them?

Comment: in the link below i run the query (which you send me but i changed startdate[rezervasyon_gt=2012-01-01] and enddate[rezervasyon_ct=2012-01-03]) with the database which i send you and the result is Eco-2 Lux-4 Norm-3 ,but the result must be like this, Eco-2 Lux-4 Norm-2
[DataBase](http://verigrup.net/OTELDATABASE.txt)

Comment: @Mehmet: You need to compare the booking end date with the query period start date, and vice versa - so the condition should be `r.rezervasyon_gt <= '2012-01-03' and '2012-01-01' <= r.rezervasyon_ct`, not the other way round; if you do so, you should find the query returns the results Eco-2 Lux-4 Norm-2. (Otherwise, you are only excluding rooms where the booking runs for the **whole** query period, not where there is a booking for **any part** of the query period.)

Answer (score 0):

```
select
      RoomType.tip_adi,
      sum( if( Rooms.oda_id = BookedRooms.rezervasyon_oda_id, 0, 1 ) as AvailableCount
   from 
      oteldb.oda Rooms

         LEFT JOIN ( select distinct
                           res.rezervasyon_oda_id
                        from 
                           oteldb.rezervasyo res
                        where
                              res.rezervasyon_gt between '2012-01-22' and '2012-01-03'
                           OR res.rezervasyon_ct between '2012-01-22' and '2012-01-03' 
                   ) BookedRooms
            on Rooms.oda_id = BookedRooms.rezervasyon_oda_id

         JOIN oteldb.tip  RoomType
            on Rooms.oda_tip_id = RoomType.tip_id
```

Comment: DRapp Thanks, typo in the query. :/

1 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( if ( Rooms.oda_id = BookedRooms.rezervasyon_oda_id, 0, 1 )) as AvailableCount,' at line 3 Query1.qry 3 7

Comment: @Mehmet, change from IF(condition, true answer, false answer) to a Case/when condition.

Comment: :/ 1 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sum( case when Rooms.oda_id = BookedRooms.rezervasyon_oda_id                  th' at line 1 Query1.qry 1 37

Comment: @Mehmet, got it... my eyes missed it... I had no comma after the FIRST field, and had an EXTRA comma after the last field, but before the FROM clause (Doooohhhh!!! :)  Anyhow, I put it back to the SUM( IF() ) construct...